# Running Java from command. Java errors with -cp and without (JDBC error / Class not found)

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath, javac

I am trying to compile and run a program from the command line. When we compile it, we do -cp and link it to our jdbc jar.
    `javac -cp jdbc.jar *.java`

If we then just do:
   `java debugger`
We then get an error saying that the driver can't be found.

However, if we do:
`java -cp jdbc.jar debugger`
Then we get an error saying that the class Debugger can't be found.

Which way do we need to do it? Since neither is working, any suggestions on what we might need to check to fix the correct method?

Many thanks from a tired group of students!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to tell the java command where the javac command left the .class files. Perhaps

```
java -cp .:jdbc.jar Debugger
```

would do the job in your case?

Comment: Thanks! We just tried that and we still class not found error. Glad to know this is the right method though.

Comment: @PFranchise Maybe you don't have the directory structure correct. It has to match your package. Do you declare your class to be in a `package`?

Comment: @Nos we actually just removed everything from separate packages and put all the classes in the default package. So if everything is in one package (directory in command line), shouldn't java -cp .:jdbc.jar Debugger work?

Comment: Where is Debugger.class? Right in the current directory? Or perhaps in 'output' or some such, in which case that replaces '.'.

Comment: I appreciate the help. It turns out our problem was sort of unrelated, but we still used your answer to run it. Thanks and have a great night!

Answer (score -1):

I believe it should be -classpath not -cp.
Please check the javac documentation and also [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)

Comment: I am fairly certain that -cp is just short for -classpath and works the same.

Comment: Either option is valid: -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files> OR 
 -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>                A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files.